I am learning on how to make AI trainer from a tutorial , but when i try to run my code in pycharm i get this error
The youtube tutorial i am watching is Build a Personal AI Trainer by Murtaza workshop i copied each and every step but his code run while faced this error
Main Code
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import PoseModule as pm

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/amand/PycharmProjects/PoseEstimationProject02/Angle tracker/curls.mp4")

detector = pm.poseDetector()

while True:
    #success, img = cap.read()
    #img = cv2.resize(img, (1280, 720))
    img = cv2.imread("squats.jpg")
    img = cv2.resize(img, (540, 960))
    img = detector.findPose(img)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

code of PoseModule
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import math


class poseDetector():

    def __init__(self, mode=False, model_complexity=1, upBody=False, smooth=True,
                 detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):

        self.mode = mode
        self.upBody = upBody
        self.smooth = smooth
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
        self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.upBody, self.smooth,
                                     self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)

    def findPose(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)
        if self.results.pose_landmarks:
            if draw:
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, self.results.pose_landmarks,
                                           self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, draw=True):
        self.lmList = []
        if self.results.pose_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(self.results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                h, w, c = img.shape
                # print(id, lm)
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                self.lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        return self.lmList

    def findAngle(self, img, p1, p2, p3, draw=True):

        # Get the landmarks
        x1, y1 = self.lmList[p1][1:]
        x2, y2 = self.lmList[p2][1:]
        x3, y3 = self.lmList[p3][1:]

        # Calculate the Angle
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y3 - y2, x3 - x2) -
                             math.atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2))
        if angle < 0:
            angle += 360

        # print(angle)

        # Draw
        if draw:
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), 3)
            cv2.line(img, (x3, y3), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 10, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 15, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), 10, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), 15, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (x3, y3), 10, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (x3, y3), 15, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, str(int(angle)), (x2 - 50, y2 + 50),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        return angle

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('PoseVideos/1.mp4')
    pTime = 0
    detector = poseDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findPose(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[14])
            cv2.circle(img, (lmList[14][1], lmList[14][2]), 15, (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

        angle = detector.findAngle(img, 11, 13, 15)
        print("Angle:", angle)

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (70, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 0), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

error i am getting
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\amand\PycharmProjects\PoseEstimationProject02\Angle tracker\main.py", line 8, in <module>     detector = pm.poseDetector()   File "C:\Users\amand\PycharmProjects\PoseEstimationProject02\PoseModule.py", line 20, in _init_     self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.upBody, self.smooth,   File "C:\Users\amand\PycharmProjects\PoseEstimationProject02\.venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\pose.py", line 146, in _init_     super()._init_(   File "C:\Users\amand\PycharmProjects\PoseEstimationProject02\.venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 259, in _init_     self._input_side_packets = {   File "C:\Users\amand\PycharmProjects\PoseEstimationProject02\.venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 260, in <dictcomp>     name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)   File "C:\Users\amand\PycharmProjects\PoseEstimationProject02\.venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 562, in _make_packet     return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data) TypeError: create_bool(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:     1. (arg0: bool) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet  Invoked with: 0.5
What's the cause of this error?

Your tutorial seems to be outdated. Better refer to examples from the the official docs. Also better use named parameters instead of positinal parameters. This is more robust and can help to get better error messages if an API has changed.
